# how can we make filestream from a ref variable of a syncfusion pivot table

Tags: c#, pdf, pivot-table, visual-studio-2022, syncfusion-blazor

Iam working on Visual Studio 2022,Syncfusion blazor c#.I have a pivotTable and pivotchart in a single razor page I wanted to export both in a single file. So for achieving that an we able to get filestream from ref variable of pivot table.  Please find below my pivot table:
<SfPivotView TValue="dtoDailyFee" @ref="@Pivot" Height="@GridHeight" Width="100%" MinHeight="@GridHeight" AllowExcelExport="true" AllowPdfExport="true" ShowGroupingBar="true" EnableValueSorting=true ShowTooltip=false ShowFieldList="true" EnableVirtualization="true">

i wanted to have a filestream from a ref variable of a syncfusion pivot table.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.